# Java root cause java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I am new to Java and given the task to fix a bug and the issue is as follows. It would be really great if you give suggestions/ideas what is this issue and how can I fix this.:

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:453)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:368)


root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:858)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:791)
    org.apache.jsp.CustMaint.Jsp.ProfProfileDetails_jsp._jspService(ProfProfileDetails_jsp.java:4016)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:368)


root cause 

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5.17 logs.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/5.5.17
```

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow! For the case you didn't notice, whenever you're inside the message editor, you can verify the messag formatting in the preview area below the message editor. Please pay some extra attention to this in the future :)

Comment: We would need to see the stack trace of the root cause (from the tomcat logs) to be able to even comment.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap-s

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426617/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-in-java

Answer (score 7):

Here's what the Tomcat guys have to say:

> An Out Of Memory can be thrown by
>   several causes:
>
> - A servlet trying to load a several
>     GBytes file into memory will surely
>     kill the server. These kind of errors
>     must be considered a simple bug in our
>     program.
> - To compensate for the data
>     your servlet tries to load, you
>     increase the heap size so that there
>     is no room to create the stack size
>     for the threads that need to be
>     created. The memory required by each
>     thread will vary by OS but can be as
>     high as 2M by default and in some OS's
>     (like Debian Sarge) is not reducible
>     with the `-Xss` parameter. 1 Rule of
>     Thumb, use no more than 1G for heap
>     space in a 32-bit web application.
> - Deep recursive algorithms can also
>     lead to Out Of Memory problems. In
>     this case, the only fixes are
>     increasing the thread stack size
>     (`-Xss`), or refactoring the algorithms
>     to reduce the depth, or the local data
>     size per call.
> - A webapp that uses lots
>     of libraries with many dependencies,
>     or a server maintaining lots of
>     webapps could exhauste the JVM PermGen
>     space. This space is where the VM
>     stores the classes and methods data.
>     In those cases, the fix is to increase
>     this size. The Sun VM has the flag
>     `-XX:MaxPermSize` that allows to set its size (the default value is 64M)
> - Hard references to classes can prevent the
>     garbage collector from reclaiming the
>     memory allocated for them when a
>     `ClassLoader` is discarded. This will
>     occur on JSP recompilations, and
>     webapps reloads. If these operations
>     are common in a webapp having these
>     kinds of problems, it will be a matter
>     of time, until the PermGen space gets
>     full and an Out Of Memory is thrown.

**Source:** [Tomcat Wiki: OutOfMemory](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/OutOfMemory)

Comment: `Deep recursive algorithms can also lead to Out Of Memory problems. In this case, the only fixes are increasing the thread stack size (-Xss), or refactoring the algorithms to reduce the depth, or the local data size per call.` That causes **StackOverflow** Error, both are VirtualMachineError but it's beyond the point

Comment: And using direct buffers can cause OOM, just as fine.

Comment: @bestsss: or `OutOfMemoryError` when the stack isn't overflow yet, but memory is due to the expensive job during each recursion step.

Comment: @BalusC, - read again: "-Xss" stack size, anything to do w/ heap? In this case any ideas to reduce depth, anything at all of the suggestions would be absolutely out of place. Converting the recursion to iteration will cost even more heap! Tomcat Wiki is plain wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Well... who *really* caused the out of memory error?

If you ate 8 slices of pizza and you are full, is it the last slice that caused the out of stomach error?

Comment: lol! can't really up-vote. But if there is a "like" button, I would surely click for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is not easy to nail down based on just the stacktrace. It at least boils down to that you've either a memory leak in your application (the code is keeping (unnecessarily) too much objects for an (unnecessarily) long time in memory), or the server simply doesn't have enough memory in order to be able to run your webapp (simply because it is designed that way to require many memory).

To detect and fix memory leaks, use a Java profiler. If you don't have any memory leaks, i.e. the memory usage is stable but the code just really need that much memory, then simply give the server more memory to work with. The profiler is however still useful to spot memory holes in your webapp and optimize code accordingly.

If you're using Eclipse, use [TPTP profiler](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t52038.html) or if you're using Netbeans, use builtin [VisualVM profiler](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/profiler-intro.html). Or when you're using standalone VisualVM, check [this blog](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/monitoring-tomcat-with-java-visualvm) how to monitor Tomcat with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Heap Analysis Tool ([JHAT](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html)) with Eclipse MAT http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ to analyse what's going on inside JVM. What is eating how much memory. See the profile and then see the code causing that.

You can also use [JConsole](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html), it's dead easy to set it up. And you can see stuffs 'live'. TPTP is also a good option, unfortunately, I find it hard to configure.